# WPF Binding in ItemTemplate for custom ItemControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, datatemplate, itemtemplate

I add a WPF custom control and make it derive from ItemsControl. The class is called IC4 and is declared as follows:

```
public class IC4 : ItemsControl
```

I add the following properties to it:

```
    public class P
    {
        public string S { get; set; }
        public string T { get; set; }
    }

    public List<P> LP { get; set; } = new List<P>();
```

Then in the constructor I do the following:

```
    public IC4()
    {
        LP.Add(new P { S = "fred", T = "jim" });
        LP.Add(new P { S = "fred", T = "jim" });
        this.ItemsSource = LP;
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
```

Visual studio added a style entry to themes/generic.xaml - I have modified it as follows:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:IC4}">
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <!-- this is almost certainly wrong: -->
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=S}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:IC4}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <ItemsPresenter/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

In mainwindow.xaml I added:

```
    <StackPanel>
        <Label Content="before"/>
        <local:IC4 ItemsSource="{Binding LP}"/>
        <Label Content="after"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

I am fairly certain the binding for the Textbox in the data template is incorrect since I get the following runtime error (shown in the output window):

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'S' property not found on 'object' ''ContentPresenter' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=S; DataItem='ContentPresenter' (Name=''); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```

How do I set the binding to be able to show the S elements of the LP property?

(Note that for the sake of simplicity I am not interested in property change notifications).

Thanks

Comment: In addition to what [dkozl said](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35161082/302677), you are also hardcoding your DataContext in your constructor, which means that whatever you try to pass to it, such as `ItemsSource="{Binding LP}"`, will not work as expect. You should never hardcode your DataContext in any UserControl like this because it prevents any other data from being used with that UserControl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see it should be just

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=S}"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

`DataContext` of each item, so for everything in your `ItemTemplate`, will be an instance of `P` class so all you should need to specify is the `Path`